# Problems with clicking a button with Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click this button but the problem is that the button class there is used multiple times within the website, span class is also used multiple times.

[Classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aW7FD.png)

Haven't been able to find a proper tutorial on how to do it.

Any help on how to target this button to be able to click it?

Comment: Please, show the code that doesn't work

Comment: You can use adjacent elements to identify the xapth for that button. Sharing the html would help us help you :)

Answer (score 0):

If a class is used multiple times, you should use another method to get the element.
In selenium there  is lots of methods to locate html elements

> Locating Elements
>
> There are various strategies to locate elements in a
>   page. You can use the most appropriate one for your case. Selenium
>   provides the following methods to locate elements in a page:

```
find_element_by_id

find_element_by_name

find_element_by_xpath

find_element_by_link_text

find_element_by_partial_link_text

find_element_by_tag_name

find_element_by_class_name

find_element_by_css_selector
```

The relevant [documentation is here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html).